# Short-Circuit Evaluation of Logical Expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I am learning JavaScript and going through the ***JavaScript: The Complete Reference, Third Edition 2012***. Considering the abstract from the same book.

Like many languages, JavaScript ***short circuits*** the evaluation of a ***logical AND (&&)*** or ***logical OR (||)*** expression once the interpreter has enough information to infer the result. For example, if the ***first expression of an ||*** operation is ***true***, there really is no point in evaluating the rest of the expression, since the entire expression will evaluate to true, regardless of the other value. Similarly, if the ***first expression of an && operation*** evaluates to ***false***, there is no need to continue evaluation of the right-hand operand since the entire expression will always be false. The script here demonstrates the effect of short-circuit evaluation:

```
    var x = 5, y = 10;

    // The interpreter evaluates both expressions
    if ( (x >>= 5)  &&  (y++ == 10) )
        document.write("The y++ subexpression evaluated so y is " + y);

    // The first subexpression is false, so the y++ is never executed
    if ( (x << 5) && (y++ == 11) )
        alert("The if is false, so this isn't executed. ");

    document.write("The value of y is still " + y);
```

My ***O/P*** gets reflected as :

```
The value of y is still 10
```

whereas that of author's as:

```
The y++ subexpression evaluated so y is 11
The value of y is still 11
```

I see that this expression doesn't gets executed:

```
if ( (x >>= 5)  &&  (y++ == 10) )
```

I see the red line drawn under the second '&' in the above expression in Eclipse IDE with this:

```
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is 5 which is binary 101, (x >>= 5) is therefore zero, x is assigned zero, and y++ in the first statement is not executed.

(x << 5) is likewise zero since x is now zero, so the y++ in the second statement also does not execute. The value of y remains 10, since no y++ is executed.

I don't know where your author is getting y == 11 from, it's wrong.

The IDE error is a red herring - it does not understand your file contains javascript (or you delimiited the javascript incorrectly) and is trying to parse it as XML / HTML.

Comment: (Are you certain you didn't mistake <<= for >>= when typing?)

Comment: Oh, i see there is a misprint in that page. It's also given for document.write("<<pre>>"); and document.write("<</pre>>"); which must be only <pre>. And this is only for greater than or less than signs. I will mark your answer.